# Combining PDF of two variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have two distributions which can be fitted by f(x) and by g(y) respectively. To simplify the problem, imagine f(x) is a Gaussian plus a polynomial (representing signal and background respectively) and g(y) is also a Gaussian plus a polynomial. I would like to calculate the probability that x is signal and y is signal. If x and y are independent, I would just calculate the probability for f(x) to be signal and multiply it by the probability of g(y) to be signal. However, if they are not, then how should I proceed? An idea is to plot the pairs (x,y) so that I can use h(z) which would be the PDF that describes the signal and background of the two dimensional distribution. Given that I know f(x) and g(y) is there a way to combine them to form h(z)?

Comment: The joint distribution of $(x,y)$ depends on how $x$ and $y$ “correlate”. There can be *many* possible couplings of $(x,y)$ with the prescribed marginals $f$ and $g$.

Comment: This is confusing. You want to add a polynomial to the Gaussian density function? The first would suggest a finite domain and the second an infinite one. Also please expand on exactly how they correspond to signal and noise.

Comment: @Ali, the nature of my problem is particle physics. The domain will be finite since the PDFs will be fitted in a specific mass range. In this example, the Gaussian function describes well the shape of the events that come from a true particle (for example the mass of two photons that come from a pi0), while the background may be from the mass of two photons that do not come from a pi0. In other words, the problem above is trying to find the probability that I have a particle A and a particle B.

Comment: @nejimban, do you know what are some type of couplings that I could explore? or, perhaps a way of testing the type of correlation that _x_ and _y_ may have?

Comment: @skeer: a start could be [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).

Comment: So I guess you need expressions for $\mathbb{P}\left(x,y\mid \text{Signal}\right)$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(x,y\mid \text{Background}\right)$? Then Bayes. For the first at least, copulas would be overkill. While a distribution with Gaussian marginals does not *have* to be Gaussian itself, that would be a very natural assumption to make! Since you seem already to know the mean and variance of each, the only extra parameter you would need to measure is correlation (signal only). Can you do that?

Comment: @Ali, unfortunately I don't know a way to measure the correlation. Using Bayes theorem should work. However, in practice, it seems to matter whether I chose particle A or B first. I am still exploring the reasons behind this discrepancy. Perhaps there are some errors on the calculation procedures or other areas which are not within the scope of the discussion.
I will continue to explore Bayes, but also I will try use copulas. Having both methods come to an agreement (in practice) will help me make an argument to chose the simpler for future research. Thank you both for the helpful comments.

Comment: If you are viewing Bayes and copulas as alternatives to one another then at least one of us has the wrong end of the stick :)

Comment: @Ali, if one of us is wrong, it is probably me... I just learned copulas existed in this discussion... Here is what I understood, by using copulas I will be able to link the two distributions, and write a 2D PDF that consist on variables _x_ and _y_ . With this, I would be able to calculate the probability that particle A and B are both signal. Alternatively, I could use Bayes theorem to calculate the probability that A and B are both signal. For this I need to find the probability of A chosen B and multiply it by the probability of B.  Is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: The formulation of Bayes' Theorem I had in mind was this one:
$$
  \mathbb{P}\left(\text{S}\mid x,y\right)
  =
  \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(x,y \mid \text{S}\right)
    \mathbb{P}\left(\text{S}\right)}
 {\mathbb{P}\left(x,y \mid \text{S}\right)
   \mathbb{P}\left(\text{S}\right)
 + \mathbb{P}\left(x,y \mid \text{B}\right)
    \mathbb{P}\left(\text{B}\right)}.
$$
I don't know how else you would get from "by using copulas I will be able to link the two distributions and write a 2D PDF" to your stated aim "calculate the probability that particle A and B are both signal".